How do I access the "events" array elements in Fullcalendar within my Angular project?
So, I'm trying to implement a small calendar onto my website homepage and this is how I'm getting it done thorugh the Fullcalendar Angular guide:
home.component.ts
export class HomeComponent {


  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
    dateClick: (arg) => this.handleDateClick(arg),
    events: [
      { title: 'Primo Evento', date: '2024-04-06' },
      { title: 'Secondo Evento', date: '2024-04-13' }
    ]
  };

  handleDateClick(arg: any) {
    alert('date click! ' + arg.dateStr)
  }
}

Now, the problem is that I'd like to display the "title" parameter (e.g. "Primo Evento") into the alert that pops up once a certain date is clicked, but I don't know how to access the "events" array inside the CalendarOptions. I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to find a specific guide for doing this within an Angular project.
The only things I've found in the Fullcalendar official website are specific for Js and they use methods like "getEvents()" that I can't seem to be able to invoke in the Angular project.
Thanks in advance to anyone that could help!

I understand the concern and to fully leverage the fullCalendar features its better to use the CalednarAPI in the .ts file and you can almost do every operation with that.
in .html
<full-calendar #calendar [options]="calendarOptions()" [events]="eventsPromise | async">
                            </full-calendar>

in .ts file
export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;
  public calendarApi: Calendar;
  eventsPromise = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
      dateClick: arg => this.handleDateClick(arg),
      events: [
          { title: 'Primo Evento', date: '2024-04-06' },
          { title: 'Secondo Evento', date: '2024-04-13' }
      ]
  };

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.calendarApi = this.calendarComponent?.getApi();
  }

  handleDateClick(arg: any) {
      alert('date click! ' + arg.dateStr);
  }
}

Now using this.calendarApi and eventsPromise will let you manipulate the events array and try to remove the events from calendarOptions.events
Hope this helps :)

Could you please explain more about this CalendarApi you're talking about?
I tried implementing it like the one you wrote and added to my alert this piece:
this.calendarApi.view.calendar
but it doesn't display what I need, it displays an "[object Object]"
also, before it showed me the events title in the calendar grid once it loaded the page, but now it doesn't display them anymore
Thank you for further clarification!

i didn't understand the problem you had, like you can dynamically update the events using this this.calendarApi object, i'd love to give my insights on this if you can make a stackblitz example for this one.
